# Consume Remote file using Kafka Connect FileSystem Connector

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

*We got a new requirement to read different files from file server. To accomplish this I tried to use Kafka Connect FileSystem Connector from confluent which utilizes Hadoop FS to process files and used SFTP protocol. I am able to connect to remote server, read file, extract each record and publish to kafka topic. But source connector is only able to read files from /home/usr directory and not from any other directory. Here are source connector configurations and how to configure to read from different folder like /systemname/domain/inbound.

```
name=file-stream-demo-standalone
connector.class=com.github.mmolimar.kafka.connect.fs.FsSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
fs.uris=sftp://username:password@hostserver
topic=demo_file_reader_sftp
policy.class=com.github.mmolimar.kafka.connect.fs.policy.SleepyPolicy
policy.fs.fs.sftp.host=hostserver
policy.sleepy.sleep=10000
policy.recursive=false
policy.regexp=^.*\.OUT$
policy.batch_size=0
policy.cleanup=none
file_reader.class=com.github.mmolimar.kafka.connect.fs.file.reader.TextFileReader
file_reader.batch_size=0*
```

Comment: I'd suggest using Nifi rather than SFTP or Kafka Connect for reading from HDFS

Comment: you could mount the remote folders (NFS, ...) and make the connector read from the local  shared folder

Comment: @OneCricketeer We are not reading from HDFS but from remote file server. Kafka connect is able to read from file server but only from parent directory.

Comment: Ah. Still, Nifi ListSFTP processor doesn't depend on the Hadoop library implementation of the SFTP protocol, which could be your limiting factor here. Otherwise, the server is limiting what directories are available to access

Comment: @aran Mounting is not a option for us we are deploying these connectors on openshift

Comment: well seems like possible. anyway, is just a suggestion. https://www.openshift.com/blog/mounting-cifs-shares-in-openshift and https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/nodes/containers/nodes-containers-volumes.html

Comment: we are not allowed to use that option. This is ruled out and for same reason relying on SFTP

Comment: hm, I understand. I should follow @OneCricketeer's advice here, even if you had to change some parts of the architecture

Comment: You could try `sftp://username:password@hostserver/path`... Otherwise, opening a github issue with that connector author would get a more direct answer

Comment: @OneCricketeer already tried and didn work. May be opening github issue will help. Thank you